# How we can make array of map view region?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to know that how we can make array of map view region and retrieve value from that.Is anybody knows than please help me.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: that means you need to know about region of map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i find solution after lot's of effort.

```
//In
NSData *personData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&region length:sizeof(region)];
NSMutableArray *personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[personArray addObject:personData];

// out
NSData *personData1 = [personArray objectAtIndex:0];
MKCoordinateRegion teregion;
[personData1 getBytes:&teregion];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own class with methods addRegion and removeRegion and the property `MKMapView * mapView`.
p.s. to get more detailed response you should provide more information....

Comment: Thanks that will be good idea.But if you asking for more detail so i can tell that my map view region will change by user dragging and i want to keep record of each region.